# Excel COUNTIFS OR function for non-exclusive match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet of orders of fruits.
The varieties of fruits contained in a given order are all written in the same cell, coma separated.
If I want to get the number of orders that include bananas, I do the following

```
=COUNTIFS('Order List'!C:C,F$1,'Order List'!AG:AG,"*Banana*")
```

If I want to get the number of orders that include oranges, I do the following

```
=COUNTIFS('Order List'!C:C,F$1,'Order List'!AG:AG,"*Orange*")
```

This works.

Now I want to know how many orders include bananas and/or oranges.
The sum of the 2 previous results does not work, since any order including both Oranges and Bananas would be counted twice.

I could not find a way to write the regular expression that matches the case where both appears (to subtract the intersection), because 1) there is no ordering in the list, so banana could appear before or after orange and 2) because the number of intersections grows too fast when more items are in the list.

It seems a simple problem but I haven't figured out how to do this, your help is very much appreciated !

[image: Data example]

Comment: Which version of excel do you have? If it is `Excel365` with dynamic formula access then you can do it easily by `FILTER()` formula.

Comment: Thanks @Harun24HR for your advice. I learned something. I do work with Excel365 and I could use it, but I also collaborate with people working wiith older version (say down to 2013).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MMULT(IFERROR(FIND(TRANSPOSE(B1:B2),A1:A5),0),MOD(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(B1:B2))),1)+1)>0))
```

I think you'll need to CSE-enter this pre-Excel365.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a trick. First SUM both individual result then substract result counting contains both. Like below-

```
=COUNTIF(B3:B6,"*Banana*")+COUNTIF(B3:B6,"*Orange*")-COUNTIFS(B3:B6,"*Banana*",B3:B6,"*Orange*")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harun24HR. Good solution for 2 items! Unfortunately this does not scale well with broader choice (in my practical case I have about 20 items, so it is not doable)

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of replica of your actual data to your post for better understanding?

Comment: Hi  Harun24HR, I added an example in the original post. The real data is confidential, but this will give you an idea. See the real data as 100 possible fruit/vegetables, and bout 20k orders. I hope this helps.